# How to use Select query result (array) to the new query and display result for each value?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch the item name from one table and use that name to calculate the the value using name from another table.

1. I am using select query to fetch the result rows:

```
SELECT itemname FROM tablename
```

2. I want to use the result array or array value one by one to run my next query.

```
    SELECT SUM(quantity) as inward FROM inward_details WHERE item_name='$itemname'
```

There are 3 tables,

1. Item
2. Inward
3. outward

What I want to do is get the item list from the item table with select query then get the quantity for the item from inward and the quantity from outward then subtract the inward quantity from outward quantity and echo result.

E.g item name is pen and inward quantity is 20 and outward quantity is 5, 
Then I want to display result as pen 15 (20-5)

But I want it for all the items from item table.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the results you want with only one query, using a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT t.itemname, 
       COALESCE(SUM(i.quantity), 0) AS inward,
       COALESCE(SUM(o.quantity), 0) AS outward,
       COALESCE(SUM(i.quantity), 0) - COALESCE(SUM(o.quantity), 0) AS movement
FROM tablename t
LEFT JOIN inward_details i ON i.item_name = t.itemname
LEFT JOIN outward_details o ON o.item_name = t.itemname
GROUP BY t.itemname
```

We use a `LEFT JOIN` so that if there are no `inward_details` rows associated with an item we still get a row, and we `COALESCE` the `SUM` so that a `NULL` result for that situation results in a 0 value.

Comment: @DigvvijayZiite I have updated my answer based on the changes you made to your question. Please let me know if this meets your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could use hidden input in HTML with the row values inside within a `while` or `for` loop, this means that the inputs won't be shown in the browser. With back-end code(PHP) you can easily execute math calculations and proceed to insert. Hope this helps :-)